# Page faults and kernel panics on iphone

Tags: memory, jailbreak, crash

I am an iOS user and i have recently started ecountering various issues on my iphone. Given statistics given by the system monitor app about 800 mb of my 1gb memory is used almost all of the time.In addition the page fault number goes up thousands per second. I have also recently started encountering what I think are kernel panics on my iphone. The screen goes blue and my headphones make a crackling noise. I can not be sure however because nothing appears in the error logs.Another issue is that apps wont open sometimes until i kill the last opened application.I am on a jailbroken iOS 8 device and am wondering if the page faults and memory have anything to do with the problems I'm encountering or it they're normal. I also want to know if it's software or hardware and how to fix it if possible. Many thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a hardware issue, not a software issue.

Comment: I'm on a jailbroken iPhone 5s running 8.3 and I have not experienced any of the issues you're describing. I don't use a lot of tweaks though. If it were me, I'd start by removing everything but the essential packages. Put it back how it was right after you jailbroke it. Then see how it does. If it starts running better, you'll know it's jailbreak related. And if it's still behaving the same, you'll know it's probably hardware related.

Answer (score 1):

With a jailbreak it's hard to know for sure what's going on, but I'd restore your device and update to the latest official version of iOS.  I know that you might want to keep your jailbreak, so this may not be a great solution for everyone.